# Fail to import torchtext KeyError: 'SP_DIR'

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, conda, torchtext

I failed to import torchtext with the following error. I tried it with a fresh conda env install (under a different python version) and still got the same issue.

Originally I was able to use torchtext (I remember installed from pip) in an env of python 3.11, but then it raised error with the dataset module, so I updated torchtext with pip and started getting kernel crush for pytorch import. So I did some uninstall and install of the pytorch and torchtext packages from different sources (conda or pip) and couldn't fix the issue. Even a new conda env using python 3.10 raised the same error. I don't know what is messed up.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 1
----> 1 import torchtext

File ~/miniconda3/envs/ml2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchtext/__init__.py:6
      3 from torch.hub import _get_torch_home
      5 # the following import has to happen first in order to load the torchtext C++ library
----> 6 from torchtext import _extension  # noqa: F401
      8 _TEXT_BUCKET = \"https://download.pytorch.org/models/text/\"
     10 _CACHE_DIR = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(_get_torch_home(), \"text\"))

File ~/miniconda3/envs/ml2/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchtext/_extension.py:7
      4 import torch
      5 from torchtext._internal import module_utils as _mod_utils
----> 7 _LIB_DIR = Path(os.environ[\"SP_DIR\"]) / \"torch\" / \"lib\"
     10 def _get_lib_path(lib: str):
     11     suffix = \"pyd\" if os.name == \"nt\" else \"so\"

File ~/miniconda3/envs/ml2/lib/python3.10/os.py:680, in _Environ.__getitem__(self, key)
    677     value = self._data[self.encodekey(key)]
    678 except KeyError:
    679     # raise KeyError with the original key value
--> 680     raise KeyError(key) from None
    681 return self.decodevalue(value)

KeyError: 'SP_DIR'
```

```
# packages in environment at /Users/cecilia/miniconda3/envs/ml2:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
annotated-types           0.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
appnope                   0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
brotli-python             1.1.0           py310h9e9d8ca_1    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h10d778d_5    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.11.17           h8857fd0_0    conda-forge
catalogue                 2.0.10          py310h2ec42d9_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2023.11.17         pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        3.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.7           unix_pyh707e725_0    conda-forge
cloudpathlib              0.16.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
comm                      0.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
confection                0.1.4           py310h1cef2ca_0    conda-forge
cymem                     2.0.8           py310h9e9d8ca_1    conda-forge
cython-blis               0.7.10          py310hf0b6da5_2    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.8.0           py310h9e9d8ca_1    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
double-conversion         3.3.0                he965462_0    conda-forge
exceptiongroup            1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
executing                 2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
filelock                  3.13.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
fsspec                    2023.12.2          pyhca7485f_0    conda-forge
gmp                       6.3.0                h93d8f39_0    conda-forge
gmpy2                     2.1.2           py310hb691cb2_1    conda-forge
icu                       73.2                 hf5e326d_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.6                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        7.0.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        7.0.1                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.29.0             pyh3cd1d5f_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.20.0             pyh707e725_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.19.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
joblib                    1.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            8.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.7.1           py310h2ec42d9_0    conda-forge
langcodes                 3.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
libabseil                 20230802.1      cxx17_h048a20a_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           21_osx64_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           21_osx64_openblas    conda-forge
libcxx                    16.0.6               hd57cbcb_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h0d85af4_5    conda-forge
libgfortran               5.0.0           13_2_0_h97931a8_2    conda-forge
libgfortran5              13.2.0               h2873a65_2    conda-forge
libhwloc                  2.9.3           default_h24e0189_1009    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 hd75f5a5_2    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           21_osx64_openblas    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.26          openmp_hfef2a42_0    conda-forge
libprotobuf               4.24.4               hc4f2305_0    conda-forge
libre2-11                 2023.06.02           h4694dbf_0    conda-forge
libsentencepiece          0.1.99               ha269934_5    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               hbcb3906_1    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.44.2               h92b6c6a_0    conda-forge
libtorch                  2.1.0           cpu_mkl_hc49ff94_103    conda-forge
libutf8proc               2.8.0                hb7f2c08_0    conda-forge
libuv                     1.46.0               h0c2f820_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.12.4               hc0ae0f7_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               h8a1eda9_5    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               17.0.6               hb6ac08f_0    conda-forge
markdown-it-py            3.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.4           py310hb372a2b_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mdurl                     0.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2023.2.0         h54c2260_50500    conda-forge
mpc                       1.3.1                h81bd1dd_0    conda-forge
mpfr                      4.2.1                h0c69b56_0    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
murmurhash                1.0.10          py310h9e9d8ca_1    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.4                  h93d8f39_2    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  3.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nltk                      3.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.26.3          py310h4bfa8fc_0    conda-forge
openssl                   3.2.0                hd75f5a5_1    conda-forge
packaging                 23.2               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pathy                     0.10.3          py310hecd8cb5_0
pexpect                   4.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pip                       23.3.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              4.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
preshed                   3.0.9           py310h9e9d8ca_1    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.42             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.8           py310hb372a2b_0    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pydantic                  2.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pydantic-core             2.16.1          py310h54baaa9_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.17.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyha2e5f31_6    conda-forge
python                    3.10.13         h00d2728_1_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.10                    4_cp310    conda-forge
pytorch                   2.1.0           cpu_mkl_py310h1822dd0_103    conda-forge
pyzmq                     25.1.2          py310h6b67f7f_0    conda-forge
re2                       2023.06.02           hd34609a_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h9e318b2_1    conda-forge
regex                     2023.12.25      py310hb372a2b_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.31.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
revtok                    0.0.3.1            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rich                      13.7.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sacremoses                0.0.53             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
setuptools                69.0.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
shellingham               1.5.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sleef                     3.5.1                h6db0672_2    conda-forge
smart_open                6.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
spacy                     3.7.2           py310h65d09f4_0    conda-forge
spacy-legacy              3.0.12             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
spacy-loggers             1.0.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
srsly                     2.4.8           py310h9e9d8ca_1    conda-forge
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sympy                     1.12            pypyh9d50eac_103    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.11.0            h7728843_1    conda-forge
thinc                     8.2.2           py310h076e4b7_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.13               h1abcd95_1    conda-forge
torch                     2.1.0.post103            pypi_0    pypi
torchtext                 0.15.2          py310h5de3785_4    conda-forge
tornado                   6.3.3           py310h6729b98_1    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.66.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.14.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typer                     0.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.9.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.9.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2023d                h0c530f3_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   2.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wasabi                    1.1.2           py310h2ec42d9_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.13             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
weasel                    0.3.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.42.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h775f41a_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.5                h93d8f39_0    conda-forge
zipp                      3.17.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
❯ conda list torch
# packages in environment at /Users/cecilia/miniconda3/envs/ml2:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
libtorch                  2.1.0           cpu_mkl_hc49ff94_103    conda-forge
pytorch                   2.1.0           cpu_mkl_py310h1822dd0_103    conda-forge
torch                     2.1.0.post103            pypi_0    pypi
torchtext                 0.15.2          py310h5de3785_4    conda-forge
❯ conda list numpy
# packages in environment at /Users/cecilia/miniconda3/envs/ml2:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
numpy                     1.26.3          py310h4bfa8fc_0    conda-forge
❯ conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/cecilia/miniconda3/envs/ml2:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
annotated-types           0.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
appnope                   0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
brotli-python             1.1.0           py310h9e9d8ca_1    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h10d778d_5    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.11.17           h8857fd0_0    conda-forge
catalogue                 2.0.10          py310h2ec42d9_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2023.11.17         pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        3.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.7           unix_pyh707e725_0    conda-forge
cloudpathlib              0.16.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
comm                      0.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
confection                0.1.4           py310h1cef2ca_0    conda-forge
cymem                     2.0.8           py310h9e9d8ca_1    conda-forge
cython-blis               0.7.10          py310hf0b6da5_2    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.8.0           py310h9e9d8ca_1    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
double-conversion         3.3.0                he965462_0    conda-forge
exceptiongroup            1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
executing                 2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
filelock                  3.13.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
fsspec                    2023.12.2          pyhca7485f_0    conda-forge
gmp                       6.3.0                h93d8f39_0    conda-forge
gmpy2                     2.1.2           py310hb691cb2_1    conda-forge
icu                       73.2                 hf5e326d_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.6                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        7.0.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        7.0.1                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.29.0             pyh3cd1d5f_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.20.0             pyh707e725_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.19.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
joblib                    1.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            8.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              5.7.1           py310h2ec42d9_0    conda-forge
langcodes                 3.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
libabseil                 20230802.1      cxx17_h048a20a_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           21_osx64_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           21_osx64_openblas    conda-forge
libcxx                    16.0.6               hd57cbcb_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h0d85af4_5    conda-forge
libgfortran               5.0.0           13_2_0_h97931a8_2    conda-forge
libgfortran5              13.2.0               h2873a65_2    conda-forge
libhwloc                  2.9.3           default_h24e0189_1009    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 hd75f5a5_2    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           21_osx64_openblas    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.26          openmp_hfef2a42_0    conda-forge
libprotobuf               4.24.4               hc4f2305_0    conda-forge
libre2-11                 2023.06.02           h4694dbf_0    conda-forge
libsentencepiece          0.1.99               ha269934_5    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               hbcb3906_1    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.44.2               h92b6c6a_0    conda-forge
libtorch                  2.1.0           cpu_mkl_hc49ff94_103    conda-forge
libutf8proc               2.8.0                hb7f2c08_0    conda-forge
libuv                     1.46.0               h0c2f820_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.12.4               hc0ae0f7_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               h8a1eda9_5    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               17.0.6               hb6ac08f_0    conda-forge
markdown-it-py            3.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.4           py310hb372a2b_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mdurl                     0.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2023.2.0         h54c2260_50500    conda-forge
mpc                       1.3.1                h81bd1dd_0    conda-forge
mpfr                      4.2.1                h0c69b56_0    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
murmurhash                1.0.10          py310h9e9d8ca_1    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.4                  h93d8f39_2    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  3.2.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nltk                      3.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.26.3          py310h4bfa8fc_0    conda-forge
openssl                   3.2.0                hd75f5a5_1    conda-forge
packaging                 23.2               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pathy                     0.10.3          py310hecd8cb5_0
pexpect                   4.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pip                       23.3.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              4.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
preshed                   3.0.9           py310h9e9d8ca_1    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.42             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.8           py310hb372a2b_0    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pydantic                  2.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pydantic-core             2.16.1          py310h54baaa9_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.17.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyha2e5f31_6    conda-forge
python                    3.10.13         h00d2728_1_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.10                    4_cp310    conda-forge
pytorch                   2.1.0           cpu_mkl_py310h1822dd0_103    conda-forge
pyzmq                     25.1.2          py310h6b67f7f_0    conda-forge
re2                       2023.06.02           hd34609a_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h9e318b2_1    conda-forge
regex                     2023.12.25      py310hb372a2b_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.31.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
revtok                    0.0.3.1            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rich                      13.7.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sacremoses                0.0.53             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
setuptools                69.0.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
shellingham               1.5.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sleef                     3.5.1                h6db0672_2    conda-forge
smart_open                6.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
spacy                     3.7.2           py310h65d09f4_0    conda-forge
spacy-legacy              3.0.12             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
spacy-loggers             1.0.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
srsly                     2.4.8           py310h9e9d8ca_1    conda-forge
stack_data                0.6.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sympy                     1.12            pypyh9d50eac_103    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.11.0            h7728843_1    conda-forge
thinc                     8.2.2           py310h076e4b7_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.13               h1abcd95_1    conda-forge
torch                     2.1.0.post103            pypi_0    pypi
torchtext                 0.15.2          py310h5de3785_4    conda-forge
tornado                   6.3.3           py310h6729b98_1    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.66.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.14.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typer                     0.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.9.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.9.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2023d                h0c530f3_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   2.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wasabi                    1.1.2           py310h2ec42d9_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.13             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
weasel                    0.3.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.42.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h775f41a_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.5                h93d8f39_0    conda-forge
zipp                      3.17.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

```
     active environment : ml2
    active env location : /Users/cecilia/miniconda3/envs/ml2
            shell level : 2
       user config file : /Users/cecilia/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/cecilia/.condarc
          conda version : 23.11.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.11.6.final.0
                 solver : libmamba (default)
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=skylake
                          __conda=23.11.0=0
                          __osx=14.2.1=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /Users/cecilia/miniconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /Users/cecilia/miniconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/cecilia/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/cecilia/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/cecilia/miniconda3/envs
                          /Users/cecilia/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/23.11.0 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.11.6 Darwin/23.2.0 OSX/14.2.1 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/23.11.1 libmambapy/1.5.3
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: Can  you update to Python 3.12.1?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need a lower version of torchtext?
I encountered the same problem with you. And I uninstalled my previous torchtext(0.15.2) and install torchtext(0.6.0) then fix the problem. You can have a try.

Comment: I submitted an issue at the pytorch github, and the contributor replied that torchtext is no longer actively maintained and suggested me to use alternative packages such as tokenizer from huggingface instead lol But thanks for the suggestion!